# 3-tier architecture - is there any problem if I specify BAL/BLL tier methods as static in the web application?

Tags: c#

I have already a website built on 3-tier architecture (UI, BAL/BLL and DAL). My all BAL layers methods are static methods that accepts Business Objects (Entity objects) or some other parameters (like string or int) based on that it gets or insert data from/to database.

That website has around 10K hits every day and till now I have not seen any problem in this architecture. My concern is if the number of hits will grow by many folds because my BAL/BLL methods are static it may create problem because of static methods (static method or variables are shared across requests on the servers).

I want to know that is my BAL/BLL static methods are really going to create problem for me when the visitors will increase and simultaneous hits will be there or will this work just fine?

I am sorry but I am not very expert in these things.

Answer (score 1):

You should be ok with static methods, as long as those methods are thread safe. If those methods only use/operate on parameters passed in to them than they are thread safe. (As long as each object that is passed in is thread safe, and each object those objects hold is thread safe, .... etc.)

Comment: My object that is being passed to the BAL/BLL have only properties corresponding to the database table. Apart from that I have hardly using anything to pass into BAL static methods. However in the my DAL that is being called from BAL static methods might be using few string variables throughout the class globally.

Will that create problem if my BAL is static but my DAL is not static and is not thread safe?

Comment: If you are only READING those string variables, it is thread safe in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety should not go unchecked.  Run [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/).

Answer (score 0):

Static method are untestable.
Static method make your application non scalable.
Check your architecture if you can't make them non-static.

I suggest you to make them non-static, turn your BLL classes in services, extracting interfaces and common models. Use an IoC container to inject the right BLL services.
Make your DAL a service and inject it, too.

Comment: Thanks onof, Why it is non scalable? What is the problem in it? Will multiple user will use the same data returned my the static method in case of concurrrent users?

Comment: No, but you can't test your layers, you can't reuse components and logic, you can't run unit tests, regression tests and performance tests. 
Shared variables are dangerous because you can't predict the data flow.